# Can I use this h-bridge variation for power inverter application?

Tags: h-bridge, inverter

[image]

(of course replacing the motor with the load..)

Why most inverter circuits use the classical four switches not any other variation as this one as example? i just want to reduce the number of signals to control the bridge. The classical one needs 4 signals (people refuse to connect the gates of similar states together but i don't know why..)

also, Is there any reason to prefer h bridge over push pull configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not look like a good idea.  The problem is that both top transistors can be on for a while at switch-over.  Remember that the motor make a connection too.  Think of replacing the motor with a resistor and you can see that both top transistors are initially driven on when one of the bottom transistors goes on.  Also consider that it takes a little while for each top transistor to turn off after its base voltage is raised.